# Set programatically created ReportBook as HTML5 ReportSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-reporting

A user can select multiple orders, and download all the reports as one PDF.
We used [PdfSmartCopy](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfSmartCopy.html) to merge the reports:

```
protected void Print(int[] order_ids)
{
    byte[] merged_reports;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (Document doc = new Document())
    using (PdfSmartCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, ms))
    {
        doc.Open();

        foreach (string order_id in order_ids)
        {
            Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource reportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource();
            reportSource.ReportDocument = new OrderReport();
            reportSource.Parameters.Add(new Telerik.Reporting.Parameter("order_id", order_id));

            RenderingResult result = new ReportProcessor().RenderReport("PDF", reportSource, new Hashtable());

            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(result.DocumentBytes))
            {
                copy.AddDocument(reader);
            }
        }

        doc.Close();

        merged_reports = ms.ToArray();
    }

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Expires = -1;
    Response.Buffer = false;
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.OutputStream.Write(merged_reports, 0, merged_reports.Length);
}
```

But we started using the [HTML5 ReportViewer](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/t-telerik-reportviewer-html5-webforms-reportviewer) elsewhere and we want to use it there as well to be consistent. I thought of creating a ReportBook programmatically and set it as the ReportSource of the ReportViewer, but the only thing I can set is a string. We have already used ReportBook before, but this was an actual SomeReportBook.cs that we could set through `new SomeReportBook().GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;`.

Any clue? Here is what I have at the moment:

```
protected void Print(int[] order_ids)
{
    Telerik.Reporting.ReportBook reportBook = new Telerik.Reporting.ReportBook();

    foreach (string order_id in order_ids)
    {
        Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource reportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource();
        reportSource.ReportDocument = new OrderReport();
        reportSource.Parameters.Add(new Telerik.Reporting.Parameter("order_id", order_id));

        reportBook.ReportSources.Add(reportSource); 
    }

    this.ReportViewer.ReportSource = new Telerik.ReportViewer.Html5.WebForms.ReportSource() 
    {
        Identifier = // Can't use reportBook.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also struggled with this challenge for quite some time; I would to share in case 
someone else faces such a challenge. Kindly do this.

1.Create a class that inherits from - Telerik.Reporting.ReportBook 
2.Create a method that loads all your reports in your reportbook class i.e.

```
this.ReportSources.Add(new TypeReportSource
       {
            TypeName = typeof(Report1).AssemblyQualifiedName
       });
```

3. Call you method in your class constructor
4. use the following code to set the report viewer source

   ```
    var reportSource = new Telerik.ReportViewer.Html5.WebForms.ReportSource();

       reportSource.IdentifierType = IdentifierType.TypeReportSource;
       reportSource.Identifier = typeof(ReportCatalog).AssemblyQualifiedName;//or 
   namespace.class, assembly e.g. "MyReports.Report1, MyReportsLibrary"
       reportSource.Parameters.Add("Parameter1", "Parameter1");
       reportSource.Parameters.Add("Parameter2", "Parameter2");
       ReportsViewer1.ReportSource = reportSource;
   ```

Report1 = Newly created class that inherits from Telerik.Reporting.ReportBook